# use jsduck failed to generate doc,The code framework uses Extjs

Tags: jsduck

The command line prompt error when using jsduck docs today:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfJaF.png)
Can't I use keywords like parse? But I need these in my code.

Comment: Edit your question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "parse" mentioned in error logs refers to the code of JSDuck, not to your code that it's parsing. Something unexpected happens inside JSDuck while parsing your code.

There's not much else I can tell without seeing your code. Looks like the problem is in file `CommonUtils.js`. If it's large, try to trim that file to just the minimum amount of code that's causing the crash.

If it's not clear by then, post the code here.

Comment: This file is written in some common methods, I submit it to you to see？

Comment: My file has characters such as "map", "Array", "parse", "parseInt"

Comment: These words are likely not the cause of the problem. It's best if you can show the whole file.

Comment: Sasrsoo This file is too large to upload here. Can you provide your email address? I send you.Yesterday I tried to find the problem, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really fancy digging through your large file. I suggest you try to remove parts of the file and re-run JSDuck until you find the minimal part that's still causing the crash. Then post this minimal amount of code here.